# OpenCv imread error while trying it in real-time

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, opencv3.0, face-recognition

**code:**

```
import face_recognition as fr
import os
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from time import sleep


def get_encoded_faces():
    
    encoded = {}

    for dirpath, dnames, fname in os.walk("./faces"):
        for f in fname:
            if f.endswith(".jpg") or f.endswith(".png"):
                face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + f)
                encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
                encoded[f.split(".")[0]] = encoding

    return encoded, fname


def unknown_image_encoded(img):
    
    face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + img)
    encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]

    return encoding


def classify_face(im):
    
    faces, fname = get_encoded_faces()
    faces_encoded = list(faces.values())
    known_face_names = list(faces.keys())

    img = cv2.imread(im, 1)
    
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(img)
    unknown_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img, face_locations)

    face_names = []
    for face_encoding in unknown_face_encodings:
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        name = "Unknown"

        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        face_names.append(name)

        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, top-20), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), 2)

            cv2.rectangle(img, (left-20, bottom -15), (right+20, bottom+20), (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(img, name, (left -20, bottom + 15), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 2)


    return face_names, fname

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, image = cap.read()

    recog, fname = classify_face(image)
    print(recog)

    cv2.imshow(fname, image)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face.py", line 70, in <module>
    recog, fname = classify_face(image)
  File "face.py", line 37, in classify_face
    img = cv2.imread(im, 1)
SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wbmte9m7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

The code works properly while using an image but now when I tried using it with video/real-time its throwing this error

I guess it requires the path instead of the image that is passed on to it, is there any other work around

I am trying to recognize faces in real time and the major issue with it was detecting unknown faces so when I started coding for real time I got this error.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve and what the error has to do with real-time computation. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The code and the error message don't agree. Are you running an older version of the code?

Error message:

> File "face.py", line 37, in classify_face
>
> img = cv2.imread(im, 1)

Code:

> img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

For debugging it may be helpful to display the received frame from the camera with code like the following:

```
ret, image = cap.read()
grey = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('frame', grey)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Sorry for the chaos, was trying a solution which also returned an error and I mistakenly pasted the old code in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.imread(im, 1)` requires `im` to be the filename (datatype: string) of the image that you want to read.
Using `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, you don't need to read images from files anymore, since the image that you want to classify is returned as an array from `cap.read()`.

To fix your code for using `cv2.VideoCapture`, remove `img = cv2.imread(im, 1)` from your `classify_face` method and change the method definition to

```
def classify_face(img):
```

instead of

```
def classify_face(im):
```

*Note, that the `0` option of `cv2.VideoCapture` refers to reading the live video stream from a camera with index `0`.*